# Hibernate is ignoring a column during inserts

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, field

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_TB")
public class Person implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 32423423432434;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long personId;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "VALUE")
   private String value;

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;

   @Transient
   Address address;
   //getters / setters
}
```

This is my code to create an Entity:

```
 public Person createPerson( long id, String name, String value ) {
   Person p = new Person();
   p.setId(id);
   p.setName(name);
   p.setValue(value);
   return p;
 }
```

In a different method:

```
  personCrudSvc.create(createPerson(192L, "Joe", "xyz");
```

This is the error:

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Attempt to insert null into a non-nullable column: column: VALUE  
 table: PERSON_TB in statement [insert into PERSON_TB (NAME, ID) values (?, ?)]
```

Not sure if this is related to this bug:

[Hibernate Bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4254)

I have two other tables created like this, and those are fine.

Comment: Clearly I can see that, Hibernate is pushing the wrong query to database. insert into PERSON_TB (NAME, ID) values (?, ?)

It should be insert into PERSON_TB (NAME, ID, VALUE) values (?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_TB")
public class Person implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 32423423432434;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "personId")
   private Long personId;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "VALUE")
   private String value;

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;

   @Transient
   Address address;
   //getters / setters
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference? How do I change name to "personId" when field name is ID?

Comment: It's not an issue with your code. It's an issue with Hibernate. But this workaround may work for you. Otherwise move from annotations to mapping xml. There's no other solution which I am aware

Comment: What is this bug in Hibernate? Can you elaborate?